# Break trio loop in pytest tests

Tags: python, python-trio

I need to override response for some my tests. I use pytest+ selenium. I found an example of code that can be used for that, it override response using selenium cdp and trio, also I add `pytest-trio` to make it work. Here is the code example:

```
class TestBiddersSelect:
    async def cpd(self):
         async with self.driver.bidi_connection() as connection:
            session, devtools = connection.session, connection.devtools
            await session.execute(devtools.fetch.enable())
            listener = session.listen(devtools.fetch.RequestPaused)
            async with trio.open_nursery() as nursery:
                async for event in listener:
                    if "url_example" in str(event.request.url) and event.request.method == "GET":
                        # override response
    async test_override(self):
        await self.cdp()
```

The problem is that the `async for event in listener` iterator does not stop, so the test does not complete.

Perhaps someone knows how this can be solved or can give an example of a different approach. Thanks